# Conditional compilation from .h and .cpp

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm trying to make a library file. The .cpp file has some conditional compiled lines. The code can be found at:

HMC58X3.h http://sprunge.us/hEYW

HMC58X3.cpp http://sprunge.us/faRN

HMC58X3_raw.pde http://sprunge.us/BFVj

Basically, in the Arduino sketch file `HMC58X3_raw.pde` I define ISHMC5843 and in both `HMC58X3.cpp` and `HMC58X3.h` I do have different code to be compiled depending if that flag has been enabled.

The conditional compilation seems to work for `HMC58X3.h` while it doesn't for `HMC58X3.cpp`. It always looks as if ISHMC5843 hasn't been defined. How can it be made to work?

Comment: no errors, it just don't work.. in the .cpp file it always compile the #else part of the #ifdef ISHMC5843 while it does work correctly in the .h conditional compilation.

Comment: And this happens when you compile HMC58X3.o, by itself, alone, and nothing else? How do you compile it?

Comment: @Beta Ben below has found my problem.. I guess I spent too much time working on high level languages.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `#define` is not like a global variable.  It's a pre-processor macro that only applies to the remaining text of that compile unit.  There are a couple ways to do what you want:

1. Create a `config.h` with `#define ISHMC5843` and be sure to include it everywhere (and before any other includes that reference it).
2. In your `Makefile` (probably inaccessible to you in Arduino) ensure `-DISHMC5843` appears on every compile line, typically by including it in `CFLAGS`.  (The details of how to ensure `CFLAGS` is part of your compile rule is way beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 0):

When you compile HMC58X3.cpp the compiler hasn't seen the macro definitions in HMC58X3_raw.pde. IMO, you're better of using a global boolean constant variable to achieve what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how `ISHMC58431` is defined in *either* HMC58X3.h or HMC58X3.cpp.

The definition has to be visible to the preprocessor when the file is pre-processed.  This is normally done by `#include`'ing a common file  that includes the `#define` in all files that need visibility of the macro,  or by defining the macro on the compiler command line, such as `-DISHMC58431` for example (compiler dependent).

This would of course require that the .pde file is also processed by the pre-processor, which since it has `#include` statements, I assume that it is.